# Ruby magic comment doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, encoding

Hey, I'm trying to write hebrew strings on my application. 
I added

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

To my first line to change the encoding. When I launch my program I get an encoding error.

Edit - I believe the problem happens only on my computer. I might have done something wrong, It works very well on my laptop \ other computers. If anyone has any idea anyway it would be nice to know.

KCODE doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

? I'm not quite sure but I ussualy use this for Cyrillic

```
$KCODE = 'u'
require 'jcode'
```

Answer (score 2):

Are there any blank lines at the beginning of the file? The first line must be a shebang, a coding statement, etc.

Oh, and like @fl00r said if you're not using 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

change `coding` to `encoding`, I think

`# encoding: utf-8`

http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/04/fun-with-ruby-1.html